# Coun't not find this item error while copy files on windows

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, chkdsk, ntfs-3g

I did a backup of my Linux computer on an NTFS hard drive.

When I try to delete or copy some directories in windows I have the following message: "Coun't not find this item" but with the explorer, I can click on the folder and access the files inside it.

I was thinking maybe the file system was not correct because I use Linux for the writes but `chkdsk /r /x` don't find any error.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Linux NTFS drivers *do* have issue when *writing* to NTFS-formatted partitions, and required use of a cleanup operation afterwards to finish journaling, etc. [Newer drivers *should* do better](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32292/is-ntfs-3g-safe-for-writing), so update drivers, e.g. to [NTFS-3G](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/).

Also, be sure write operations are completed, since both Linux and Windows use write-caching on permanent drives. [Try calling umount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345917/does-umount-calls-sync-to-complete-any-pending-writes) after all writes are finished.

In some cases, I've had to create a file on the Linux (ext4) partition and then use SFTP to transfer to a Windows-mounted NTFS drive, but that was also because of security issues, so that work-around should not be needed, in your case.

Comment: It's a 4 year old Ubuntu install so not so old. How to launch cleanup Operation? Is there anything better than chkdsk? I don't understand how I can see the error message and chkdsk cannot detect anything